# aol.com Network error

Tags: marketing-cloud, bounce-management

I'm getting a lot of Network Error bounces when sending emails through SFMC.

Attached Bounce Description is *"Connection lost or timed out during delivery"*

Still in the IP warming stage, but I was wondering if this is a SFMC known issue, or whether it was on my end with our domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AOL has the most stringent IP warm up volumes. You might be having deliverabilty issues if you folllowed the same volumes for the other providers. You can read more about it here : [IP Warm Up 1](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231379&type=1) and [Official IP Warm Up Documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/email_deliverability/ip_address_warming_guide/)

I would contact support to investigate this .

Also [Return Path](https://returnpath.com/) (inbox tools) provides a more complete deliverabilty tool and can be used  as an indicator of potential troubles. You can monitor your sender reputation on it and with gmail see the inbox allocation.